# a problem in writing a C# program : String separator contains 5 numbers

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

i wanna write C# program that Receive a string consisting of 5 numbers separated by commas.  Separate and print them & Write "Unauthorized list" if the string is less than 5 or empty & Print 3 smaller numbers at the end of the list.
already writre this and need your helps to complete it!

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a list of 5 numbers (seperated by ,): ");

string input = Console.ReadLine();

string errorMessage = "Invalid List. Try Again: ";

bool loopContinue = true;

while (loopContinue == true)
{
    string[] list = input.Split(',');
    if (input == " " || list.Count() < 5)
    {
        Console.Write(errorMessage);
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        loopContinue = false;
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (var i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            int.Parse(list[i]);
        }

        foreach (var x in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

        Array.Sort(list);

        Console.WriteLine("Three smallest numbers: ");
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int.Parse(list[i]);` *returns* the parsed in, it does not convert "list[i]" in-place. So you are converting it and forgetting about the converted value. You will have to catch the converted values in a *new* `int[ ]`

Comment: When you determine that there are not five items, how does the user know that your code wants them to re-enter a new value? Also, how do you know the values are numeric?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how I'd write it, using [Array.ConvertAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
int[] list = null;

string errorMessage = "Invalid List. Try Again: ";
bool valid = false;
while (!valid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a list of 5 numbers (seperated by ,): ");
    string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
    try
    {
        list = Array.ConvertAll(input, x => int.Parse(x));
        if (list.Length == 5)
        {
            valid = true;
        }                    
    } catch(Exception ex) {}
    if (!valid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }
}

// Sort list
Array.Sort(list);

// Print 3 smallest 
Console.WriteLine("Three smallest numbers: ");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` to make sure the user entered a numeric input.

like this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[list.Length];
for (var i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
     bool success = int.TryParse(list[i], out numbers[i]);
     if(!success) 
     {
        Console.Write(errorMessage);
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: The commas were already removed by the split() line: `string[] list = input.Split(',');`